# IBM WEBSPHERE 9 application server very slow on windows server 2016

Tags: performance, optimization, websphere, heap-size

I'm newly using IBM WEBSPHERE.
We have a websphere application server which is very solow and we need sometime to reboot the service and even the server.

Could anyone please assist with checking the configuration of the JVM ?
The initial heap size : 1024
Max heap size : 1280

RAM : 32 GB
64 bit OS

I have check the systemerr.log  and I have only a java error : unparseable date.
I don't have any error regarding memory.
I checked systemout.log and systemerr.log but I can't see any information regarding slowness.

Thank for your advices.

Comment: Hi everyone, finally I set initial heap size : 1 giga and max heap size : 4 giga.